# Selenium UI Automation Testing plugin in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, selenium, intellij-idea, configuration

Regarding *Selenium Support in IntelliJ IDEA*, I tend to use the methods recommended by jetbrains, which I found at

- https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2020/03/intellij-idea-2020-1-selenium-support/
- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/selenium.html (Last modified: 05 December 2022)

They both recommend the **Selenium UI Automation Testing** plugin, yet I'm not able to find it myself:

[image]

Digging deeper, I found
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/13691-selenium-ui-testing

which says it is *"Included In
Test Automation Kit"*

Yet, I'm unable to find the *"Test Automation Kit"* either.

Given that https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/selenium.html was last modified at 05 December 2022, I'm thinking that I'm missing something very obvious. Please help.

How can I have Selenium Support in IntelliJ IDEA?
How can I run Selenium scripts in IntelliJ IDEA?

Comment: It shows up for me (IntelliJ IDEA 2022.3 (Ultimate Edition)), so the question is, what IntelliJ version are you using, and is it the Ultimate or the Community edition?

Comment: To be clear the "Ultimate" label next to the title on https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/selenium.html indicates it is an Ultimate Edition feature, so it is not available in Community Edition.

Comment: Aha, I'm using the Community edition and the "Ultimate" label didn't catch my eyes. that's why. thanks @MarkRotteveel. I'll use the manually "adding libs & dirs" way then.