# How to use Selenium with IntelliJ IDE

Tags: java, selenium, intellij-idea, configuration

I followed the very detailed [How to use IntelliJ IDE & Selenium](https://www.h2kinfosys.com/blog/how-to-use-intellij-ide-selenium-webdriver/) word for word, but in the end I'm still not be able to use Selenium, getting the errors of:

`java: package org.openqa.selenium does not exist`

[image]

I'm wondering what else I'm missing from such detailed how-to article (e.g., has the selenium java package been named differently since then?).

[image]

Comment: Follow https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/selenium.html instead and use Maven for the dependencies management.

Comment: Oh that's actually the first thing that I tried @CrazyCoder, but I wasn't able to use it due to my Community edition (as I'm unable to use IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate edition). Details at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74691305/selenium-ui-automation-testing-plugin-in-intellij-idea

Comment: Use with IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate.